# Displaying The Correct Number of hearts on A Health Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a health bar using HTML and Javascript, where on the click of a link it removes one heart. That seems to be working for me. However I also want it to on reload display the same health as before. What I have so far is below. It seems to be partially working. For example, when I click the link once it removes a single heart. When I reload it though all the hearts show back up. If I click the link twice more it then shows me having lost two hearts, but shows the popup that says "You died!" It seems to be behaving how I want it to other than incorrectly displaying the hearts. What am I doing wrong?

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem("loaded") !== "loaded"){
    sessionStorage.setItem("heartcount",3);
    sessionStorage.setItem("loaded","loaded");
}

function playerLoose(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("heartcount", sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount")-1);
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") == 2){
        document.getElementById("heart1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart1").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") == 1){
        document.getElementById("heart2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart2").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") == 0){
        document.getElementById("heart3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart3").style.display = "inline";
        setTimeout(playerDie, 100);
    }
}
function playerDie(){
    
    alert("You died!")
}

function playerLoad(){
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 2){
        document.getElementById("heart1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart1").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 1){
        document.getElementById("heart2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart2").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 0){
        document.getElementById("heart3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart3").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```css
#lifebar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1%;
    z-index: 30;
    border-radius: 20vw;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 0.25%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px lightgray;
}

#hearts{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}

#noheart1{
    display: none;
}

#noheart2{
    display: none;
}

#noheart3{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body onload="return changeColor();playerLoad()">
        <script src="lives.js"></script>
        <div id="lifebar">
            <ul id="hearts">
                <li id="heart1">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="heart2">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </liv>
                <li id="heart3">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart1">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart2">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart3">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>                
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <h1 id="temp"><a href="#" onclick="playerLoose()">Page 1A</a></h1>
        <script src="lives.js"></script>
                    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `playerLoose()` try using `===` instead of `==` because `===` will be more precise, as in, it will get a better result than `==`

## Edit 1

Try this, It worked for me. If it doesn’t work for you, try changing the function names or something.

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem("loaded") !== "loaded"){
    sessionStorage.setItem("heartcount",3);
    sessionStorage.setItem("loaded","loaded");
}

function playerLoose(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("heartcount", sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount")-1);
    switch (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") {
      case 2:
        document.getElementById("heart1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart1").style.display = "";
        break;
      case 1:
        document.getElementById("heart2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart2").style.display = "";
        break;
      case 0:
        document.getElementById("heart3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart3").style.display = "";
        setTimeout(playerDie, 100);
        break;
    }
}
function playerDie(){
    
    alert("You died!")
}

function playerLoad(){
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 2){
        document.getElementById("heart1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart1").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 1){
        document.getElementById("heart2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart2").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("heartcount") <= 0){
        document.getElementById("heart3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("noheart3").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```css
#lifebar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1%;
    z-index: 30;
    border-radius: 20vw;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 0.25%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px lightgray;
}

#hearts{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}

#noheart1{
    display: none;
}

#noheart2{
    display: none;
}

#noheart3{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body onload="return changeColor();playerLoad()">
        <div id="lifebar">
            <ul id="hearts">
                <li id="heart1">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="heart2">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </liv>
                <li id="heart3">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart1">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart2">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>
                </li>
                <li id="noheart3">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px"><sub>favorite_border</sub></i>                
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <h1 id="temp"><a href="#" onclick="playerLoose()">Page 1A</a></h1>
                    
    </body>
</html>
```

## Edit 2

You could also change your load listener to `document.addEventListener(‘load’,()=>{//the function you want to execute//};`

Comment: I just tried replacing all the `==` with `===` as you suggested and now nothing is happening. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you haven’t posted all the code you are using. But it could be that the number of hearts is being updated after the page has already loaded. So what I would do, is remove the inline on load and use a function on the main js page. And then get the current session status and set it equal to a variable that the rest of the js references

Comment: I just updated my answer with code, it worked for me. Btw I’m using Github to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

document.addEventListener(‘load’,()=>{

/// get items from storage and set to variable
   playerLoad(); // you could even pass that           variable here as a param

```
 })
```

function playerLoad();